# What button control can react when the mouse is over it?

Tags: button, mouse, c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder 6 and I need something like TBitBtn, but it should react when mouse is pointing at it by changing to another image. Yes, I know I can use OnStartDoc but there is no OnStopDoc. :(

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the TBitBtn's WindowProc property to intercept the `CM_MOUSEENTER` and `CM_MOUSEENTER` messages (which were exposed as new OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave events in later BCB versions).  You can use those to update the button's Glyph as needed.